# swap function didn't work

Tags: c, swap

Why this swap method didn't work

```
void swap(int *x,int *y){

     int *temp;
     temp = x;
     x = y;
     y = temp;
}
```

Why? I think it's same as the common one..

Comment: Why are you even writing such a function when you can just `{int t = x; x = y; y = t;}` in a single line?

Answer (score 3):

C passes function arguments by value: you are only swapping copies of pointers.

If you want to swap two `int`:

```
void swap(int *x,int *y)
{
   int temp;
   temp = *x;
   *x = *y;
   *y = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are swapping the addresses stored in temporary pointers on the stack, not the values stored in the memory they point to. You want to do this instead:

```
void swap(int *x,int *y){

     int temp = *x;
     *x = *y;
     *y = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `x` and `y` behave just like local variables.
2. your code is swapping `x` and `y` values, not the values they point to.